# How can I check whether cvs2git is still running?

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2svn, cvs2git

I have trigged off cvs to git migration with cvs2svn (cvs2git) for 4 days. My repository has a size of 12 GB and it is still in pass 7.

```
pass 1: 66238 sec
pass 2: 29.96 sec
pass 3: 6.745 sec
pass 4: 106343 sec
pass 5: 2080 sec
pass 6: 3955 sec
```

So pass 1 - 6 have taken ca. 49,6 hours and pass 7 is still in progress for 48 hours without  any error message. I don't know whether anything does happen or it has hung up.

Is this a regular behavior of cvs2git? What can I do? Is there any possibility to check whether everything is ok?

Comment: Use `top` to see which processes are consuming resources. If cvs2svn is eating up memory / cpu then it's likely that it's still working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps awx | grep cvs`.

This way you can also see the PROCESS STATE CODES.

You can use `man ps` in order to understand the PROCESS STATE CODES.

Answer (score 0):

- With the command `top` you can see the processes which use most of the cpu.
- And also the load of the system (`uptime`) is an indicator that your system is doing hard work.
- Last but not least, you can use `find -mmin -3600` to check if there are any files which were recently changed (in this example: modified in the last hour).

Btw: we also had a huge repository. a lot of its size came from third-party libraries. Finally, I explicitly excluded them from conversion and put them into a separate repository (submodule). Git seems to need a lot of memory for working with big binary files.